# How to change css style value using php in a for loop?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I've downloaded this slider:

> http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/

What I want to do is to make the dot (bullet) for each slider a specific color (first is red, second is blue, etc), and not to be white for all slides.

The class that controls this issue is `.da-dots span.da-dots-current:after` (in `style.css` if you downloaded the files above).

The problem is how to change the background property of `.da-dots span.da-dots-current:after` in the `index.html` (or `index.php`) file?

The issue is that the slides are actually a number of `DIV`'s that are listed in the source code and animated using the jQuery slider above.

My `index.php` contains: http://codepad.org/6Xoelift

Comment: I would assign a class to the div that has the style you wish. Give a different class to the div based on a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you support only browsers handling [CSS3 selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), you can use the [nth-child selector](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) `:nth-child(1)`, `:nth-child(2)`, `:nth-child(3)`, … to style each dot differently.

Comment: You mean to do this : .da-dots span.da-dots-current:after:nth-child(1) {  background: white; }
.da-dots span.da-dots-current:after:nth-child(2) {  background: red; }
This didn't work :(

Comment: I think you can't use `:nth-child` with `:after` because this is a [pseudo-element](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp)

Comment: The class `.da-dots-current` might be wrong because it should logically concerns only the current slide. It's difficult to help you without live code to play with.

Comment: Also your syntax is wrong, selector comes before pseudo-element like this: `span.da-dots-current:nth-child(2):after`